# Evil text object for innermost paired delimiter?

Tags: evil

**Q:** how can I create a text object for innermost paired delimiters?

`evil` has text objects to allow us to operate on the standard
paired delimiters like parentheses, braces, brackets, quote marks,
and so on.

When I'm using the paired delimiters, though, I'm usually
looking to operate on the *innermost* pair:

```
Here's some text (and a parenthetical remark with "quotes*" in them).
```

If the `*` in "quotes" is point, I want to operate on `"quotes"`
rather than the full parenthetical expression.  In this case, I could just use the quotes text object, but I'd like to create a single, DWIM text object for the purposes of keybinding.

*How can I define a text object that will simply select the
innermost paired delimiters (as defined in some variable)?*

Comment: evil-cleverparens has a "form" text object providing this.

Comment: You can also try `targets.el`: https://github.com/noctuid/targets.el